# CursorLoader not working

Tags: java, android

please can someone assist I am trying to retrieve a list of contacts from the phone on Android. The only issue that I have in public Loader onCreateLoader the new Cursor gives me an error. The error is ? android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader?(Multiple choices..).

```
public class Contacts extends AppCompatActivity implements
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
//AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
    ...
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {

        //Starts the query
        return new CursorLoader(
            getApplicationContext(),
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION,
            SELECTION,
            mSelectionArgs,
            null
        );
    }
}
```

Removed all unnecessary bits to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Post the stacktrace please.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question new to android.. how do i do that

Comment: You can use Android Monitor in Android Studio to get it. More infor about stack trace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: thanks for the link excellent explanation.. will post now

Comment: error: cannot find symbol class CursorLoader

Answer (score 0):

import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader - did the trick